# Intersection of type-I von-Neumann algebra factors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Is the intersection of a (possibly infinite) family $\{\mathcal M_i\}$ of type-I von-Neumann algebra factors (over the same Hilbert space $\mathcal H$) again a type-I von-Neumann algebra factor?

Comment: No. By the bicommutant theorem, you are asking if the (increasing) union closure of type I factors is again type I, which is not true.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA I don't understand. It seems to me that you are using something like $(A\cap B)' = A' \cup B'$ which is not true (not even modulo bicommutant-closure). Can you elaborate further? (Ideally, with an answer containing a proof?)

Comment: $(A\cap B)'=W^*(A'\cup B')$ in general, but we need only decreasing/increasing sequence here: $A=\mbox{cl}\bigcup A_n$ can be any type for finite-dimensional factors $A_1\subset A_2\subset\cdots$. Hence $A'=\bigcap A_n'$ can have any type even though $A_n'$ are type I factors.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Oh, I think the counterexample for $(A\cap B)'\neq W^*(A'\cup B')$ I had in mind was wrong... (I assume $W^*(\dots)$ means the bicommutant here.) Do you have a reference or proof for $(A\cap B)' = W^*(A'\cup B')$? And for the fact that $\mathit{cl}\bigcup A_n$ can have any type for type-I $A_i$? (I assume $\mathit{cl}\dots$ also means bicommutant here?)

Comment: I meant by "cl" the SOT closure. Hyperfinite factors arise as the SOT-closure of the increasing union of finite-dimensional factors. It's easy to see $(W^*(A'\cup B'))'=A\cap B$. Then the bicommutant theorem implies $W^*(A'\cup B')=(A\cap B)'$.

Comment: But how do I know that the increasing union of finite type-I factors is not a **type-I** factor? Also, as a fallback, I'm interested about the finite intersection of type-I factors, but I opened a separate question for that in accordance with the MathOverflow rules.

Comment: Forgot to add the link to the new question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442906/intersection-of-finitely-many-type-i-von-neumann-algebra-factors