# Intersection of finitely many type-I von-Neumann algebra factors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $\mathcal M,\mathcal N$ are type-I von-Neumann algebra factors (over the same Hilbert space $\mathcal H$), is $\mathcal M\cap\mathcal N$ a type-I von-Neumann algebra factor?

**Notes**:

- An elementary proof would be ideal, but I also take a textbook reference.
- The comments after my [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442854/intersection-of-type-i-von-neumann-algebra-factors) indicate that this is **not** the case for an intersection of **infinitely** many factors, but they crucially rely on the "infinite" part of it.
- I know that the intersection of two von-Neumann algebras is a von-Neumann algebra.
- I don't know if the intersection of two factors is a factor.

Comment: Again, by the bicommutant theorem, you are asking what kind of von Neumann algebra is generated by finitely many type I factors. It needs not be a factor and can be quite arbitrary. The tracial free product of $M_3(\mathbb{C})$ with itself is a factor of type II_1. The proof of factoriality is not so easy (see https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-69/issue-1/Free-products-of-hyperfinite-von-Neumann-algebras-and-freedimension/10.1215/S0012-7094-93-06905-0.short), but by construction it is infinite dimensional and has a tracial state, hence not a type I factor.

Comment: Unfortunately, I lack the expertise to understand the linked paper (or even to find the result about $M_3(\mathbb C)$ in it), or to see that the tracial product you mention is indeed the closed union of finitely many type-I factors...

Comment: It's not closed union. It is $W^*(A\cup B)$ with $A\cong M_3(\mathbb{C})\cong B$, and $W^*(A\cup B)' = A' \cap B'$ is the intersection of type I factors $A'$ and $B'$. Since the type (I, II, III) is preserved under the commutant operation, the type of $A'\cap B'$ is same as that of $W^*(A\cup B)$, which is II under the tracial free product.