# Intersection of von-Neumann algebra factors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Given two von-Neumann algebra factors $\mathcal M,\mathcal N$, is $\mathcal M\cap\mathcal N$ a factor?

And how about the intersection of infinitely many factors?

**Notes:**

- I know that the intersection is a von-Neumann algebra. (This is immediate from the definition of a von-Neumann algebra as a SOT-closed algebra with adjoints and 1.)
- I know that this does not hold for *Type I* factors. (See comments [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442906/intersection-of-finitely-many-type-i-von-neumann-algebra-factors).)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, given any tracial vN algebra $A$, one could form free products $1*A*L\mathbb{F}_2=\mathcal{N}$ and $L\mathbb{F}_2*A*1=\mathcal{M}$ which provide $\mathcal{M}\cap\mathcal{N}\simeq A$, whereas $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are II$_1$ factors by virtue of being the free product of a II$_1$ factor with something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. There are subfactors $N\subset M$ with finite Jones index $[M:N]$ with $N^{\prime}\cap M=\mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{C}$. For example, consider a type $II_1$ factor $P$ and let $\alpha$ be an outer automorphism of $P$. Put $M= P\otimes M_2(C)$ and $N$ be the algebra of all diagonal matrices $(x,\alpha(x)),$ for $x\in P$.